# How exactly does lycanthropy work?  Does it mix with vampirism?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Related to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34894/how-do-i-become-a-werewolf).

Specifically, I want to know if these possibilities exist:

1. Can I become a werepire(vampwolf?), i.e. both vampire and werewolf at the same time.
2. Can you infect other NPCs as a werewolf?
3. Can I somehow infect a giant and turn it into a humongous werewolf?
4. Will infected werewolves attack other NPCs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I become a Werewolf?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34894/how-do-i-become-a-werewolf)

Comment: @LessPop, I already pointed out the other question, but my question is different as I'm asking whether or not it mixes with certain other aspects, I'm not asking how I become a werewolf.

Comment: If the answer to the other question is, "You can't become a werewolf", this question is irrelevant.

Comment: @Raven, its already been confirmed that werewolves are in skyrim.

Comment: @yx. There's dragons in Skyrim, too, but that doesn't mean you can be a Dragon.

Comment: @Raven, let me reword my comment, its already been confirmed that you can become a werewolf in skyrim [source](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Werewolf)  And who's to say you can't become one somehow ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although Everyone has told you no, there is actually a incredibly simple way to be both a vampire and a werewolf: Hircine's ring, found in the quest Ill met by moonlight. Finish the quest and you'll get the Hircine's ring, which allows Werewolf transformations without giving you the immunity to all diseases. Become a vampire, put on the ring, and Beast Form should appear in your powers menu (under magic). You select it like a shout and you transform into a werewolf, but you are still a vampire and can drink blood and all that.

Additional info: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Hircine%27s_Ring_(Skyrim)

Answer (score 10):

> 1. Can I become a werepire(vampwolf?), i.e. both vampire and werewolf at the same time.

The official strategy guide says this is not possible. The reason is because werewolves are immune to disease, which means you're protected from vampirism.

What's even more interesting is that—because of this immunity—contracting lycanthropy will cure any vampirism you have.

> 2. Can you infect other NPCs as a werewolf?
> 3. Can I somehow infect a giant and turn it into a humongous werewolf?
> 4. Will infected werewolves attack other NPCs?

You're not given any powers that would let you infect other people, so this would be a no as well.

Comment: Although, this was possible in Morrowind.

Answer (score 4):

You can become both a vampire and werewolf, however you cannot drink anyones blood, leading to your character being stuck at level four vampirism. If you don't mind everyone trying to kill you then you should do the following:

Do the companions quest until you have to drink the blood to become a werewolf, then leave the Underforge and get infected with vampirism, return to the underforge and wait three days

If it works the same way as it did for me, after waiting three days you won't instantly change into a vampire, you have about 5-8 seconds, I waited about 3-4 seconds into this, then drank the werewolf blood. As the game loads up the werewolf part you should get a message telling you that you have turned into a vampire, right after which it will load up with you being a werewolf.

Comment: interesting.  Why can't you drink blood, is it simply because you glitched your way into being both?

Answer (score 1):

I somehow contracted both long after I had drank the werewolf blood. I became a werewolf, and at least a good 30 hours of game play later contracted vampirism in a dungeon. I had, at that point, picked up but not completed the companion leader quest to kill the witches in order to cure the curse.

I am not sure if having that quest in log has something to do with having both, or if the game simply glitched out and did not give me disease immunity when I became a werewolf.

If anyone else is around this part of the companion quests and have an opportunity to test this, please let me know what happens.

Comment: hi Owen, did you succesfully become both?  Can you drink blood and transform into a werewolf?  Did you simply have the disease or were you able to become a full vampire (through waiting)?

Answer (score -1):

I did this; become a Vampire Lord, but make sure you finish the companion quest up until you are in the Underforge where Alea is changed and the blood is ready to drink it but don't drink until you are a Vampire Lord and Serena is your follower.

Go into the Underforage and have Vampire Lord form equipped. Hit the A button at the very exact time as you change into the Vampire Lord. After that you will be a Werewolf, then burst into to the Vampire Lord. Quickly revert to human form and the ask Serana to change you to a vampire. Now you are both!

Additionally, when you get the ring of Hircine complete the quest and you can use the ring for extra wolf transformations.

Answer (score -1):

Lycanoprothy lets you transform only once a day, unless you have the Ring of Hircine. It cannot mix in with vampirism without the use of mods or console commands

Answer (score -2):

Simple and quick answer to all your questions is NO.

Everything you need to know about lycanthropy is on the Elderscrolls wiki
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lycanthropy_(Skyrim)

Comment: If you could add in the details about Lycanthropy from the wiki, that would be great.  As it stands, this is not a very good answer.