# Can I be a werewolf and a vampire at the same time?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How exactly does lycanthropy work?  Does it mix with vampirism?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34905/how-exactly-does-lycanthropy-work-does-it-mix-with-vampirism)

Can I be werewolf and vampire at the same time? I would like to try both at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, becoming a werewolf cures vampirism and makes you immune to diseases.

Answer (score 3):

From: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Werewolf
"Resistance to Disease: When infected with Lycanthropy, the player is completely immune to contracting diseases. (This will prevents the player from simultaneously becoming both a Vampire and a Werewolf.)"