# Lycanthropy by being attacked by wolves?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Starting in the game, I get regularly attacked by wolves. While I can roast them quite quickly with my two hands flame spell, I sometimes get bitten before killing them.

Is there a risk of getting lycanthropy this way (which I would like to avoid (for now at least)) or is there no risk at all getting it from wild wolves?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I become a Werewolf?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34894/how-do-i-become-a-werewolf). While it isn't exactly the same, the answer is covered by that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot become a werewolf by being attacked by wolves.  The only ways to contract lycanthropy are by being attacked by a werewolf, or by drinking the blood of a werewolf in a special ritual (happens during a quest).

Comment: You can't contract lycanthropy through being attacked by a werewolf. See here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34894/how-do-i-become-a-werewolf

Answer (score 2):

Depends, was it a big wolf? Did it walk on its two hind legs? :p

More seriously though, [you can contract a disease](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Diseases_(Skyrim)) from wolves called *Rockjoint*.

**NEWSFLASH!** The Rockjoint disease is VERY BAD. Please visit your nearest Shrine of Talos immediately. Your sense of humour is at risk!

Comment: It is not "Harmless", if you are a melee character,having -25% of Melee Damage is a Pain !